# Highcharts - Add Axys properties when series are added later to Plot

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

In highcharts I use xAxys and yAxis properties to format data inserted. Code used is the same for the two axys, so I'll post only one of them:

```
$('#containers').highcharts({
....
....
yAxis: {
         tickPositioner: function () {
            var positions = [],
              tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
              increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 6);

         for (; tick - increment <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) 
             {
             positions.push(tick);
             }
               return positions;
         }
     },

    ....

series: []


});
```

I've declared `series: []` as an empty array.

Outside that I've created an array and, with addSeries function, I add series into the plot

```
var chart = $('#containers').highcharts();
        var data = [[[2,194.1],[3,95.6],[4,54.4],[5,29.9],[6,71.5], [7,106.4],[8,129.2],[9,144.0],[10,176.0],[11,135.6],[12,148.5], [13,216.4]],[294.1, 195.6, 154.4, 129.9, 171.5, 106.4, 229.2, 154.0, 276.0, 35.6, 48.5, 116.4]]
            for( i in data){ 
                chart.addSeries({
                data: data[i]
                });
            }
```

This code works well while I haven't to manipulate this data above and I can directly declare it into highcharts options. If I choose to use `addSeries` it won't work even if I comment `xAxys` and `yAxys` options.

**Question:** How can I use xAxys and yAxys properties also in case of data manipulation?

Here's a fiddle to resume my code: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/alessandronos/2n6jd/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the initial chart load with no data your `tickPositioner` function becomes an infinite loop (it crashed chrome on me).  Just protect against this on for the initial load:

```
tickPositioner: function () {
  if (this.dataMax == null){
   return []; // prevents infinite loop...   
  }

  var positions = [],
      tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
      increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 6);
  for (; tick - increment <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
      positions.push(tick);
  }
  return positions;
}
```

You should also think about not redrawing on every `addSeries`:

```
for (i in data) {
  chart.addSeries({
      data: data[i]
  }, false); // do not redraw after every series add
}
chart.redraw(); // redraw chart when done
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/2n6jd/2/).